# How to fix Maximum update depth exceeded error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am using React functional components and Firebase.

My `App.js` looks like this:

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import {PrivateRoute} from "./PrivateRoute";
import {loggedIn, firebaseObserver} from "../firebase";
import Home from './home/Home';
import Login from "./login/Login";

export default function App() {
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(loggedIn());
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        firebaseObserver.subscribe("AUTH_STATE_CHANGED", data => {
            setAuthenticated(data);
            setIsLoading(false);
        });
        return () => { firebaseObserver.unsubscribe("AUTH_STATE_CHANGED"); }
    }, []);

    return isLoading ? <div/> :
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact>
                    <Redirect to={authenticated ? "/home" : "/login"} />
                </Route>
                <PrivateRoute path="/home"
                              component={Home}
                              hasAccess={authenticated} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/login" exact
                              component={Login}
                              hasAccess={!authenticated} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>;
}
```

Inside `firebase.js` I have login methods that are being called from the Login component and the following code:

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import ReactObserver from 'react-event-observer';

export const firebaseObserver = ReactObserver();

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function() {
    firebaseObserver.publish("AUTH_STATE_CHANGED", loggedIn())
});

export function loggedIn() {
    return !!firebase.auth().currentUser;
}
```

When I start my app I get Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. And it points me to the `useEffect` inside `App.js`. What am I doing wrong? I am new to React.

Comment: `useEffect` is called only once since the deps array is empty.

Comment: Can you try that remove code 'isLoading ? <div/>'.
I think conditional rendering in App(in HOC of Router) can be a problem.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help, unfortunately. Inside my `index.js` React.Dom is rendering <Suspense fallback="loading"> <App /> </Suspense>. Could it have anything to do with it?

Comment: Why are your returning something in your useEffect?

Comment: Isn't that to way to mimic componentWillUnmount in functional components?